# spring parent child context relationship for beans in certain namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, namespaces

I want to create child spring context in which i could define bean which are good to aave. exmaple i have a jdbc datasource which is good to have but it could not be initilized i dont want the who context to crash

I achived parent child relationship using

public class OptionalFactoryBean {
    AbstractApplicationContext child;

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext parent;

public void init() {
    try {
        child = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "/java/dbpool/examples/sample/datasources/config/child-context.xml" }, parent);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Error init child context");
    }

}

public Object getBean(String name) {
    if (child != null) {
        return child.getBean(name);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

But i want to do something similar in XML. i was wondering if i could define a custom name space and register my parser as mentioned http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html

is there any hook in spring where i could define parent child relationship for beans in certain namespace?